# Создание модели в Angular 5/6

Tags: json, angular4, model

Доброго времени суток. Имеется ответ от сервера в виде json, вида:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "countryId": 1,
        "countryName": "Особь без подданства",
        "countryIdEDBO": -1,
        "countryIsArchive": 0
    },
    {
        "countryId": 2,
        "countryName": "Австралия",
        "countryIdEDBO": 36,
        "countryIsArchive": 0
    }
         ],
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://...."
    },
    "next": {
        "href": "http://...."
    },

    "last": {
        "href": "http://...."
    }
},
 "_meta": {
    "totalCount": 247,
    "pageCount": 13,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "perPage": 20
},
}
```

но прежде чем его представить на клиенте или сделать Observeble, нужно создать для него модель/интерфейс.
До этого с json работал вида:

```
{
 "id":"1",
  "name":"bla-bla"
 }
```

И для него модель была простой, вот такая:

```js
export class User{
id:string;
name:string;
}
```

Подскажите или дайте ответ, как в моем случаи сделать модель для данного ответа от сервера.

Comment: точно так же: сначала пишешь название свойства. потом его тип

Comment: Ну и вот например: http://json2ts.com/